# Is this JS code properly OOP?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to keep my JS code nice and OOP from now on. I think I've gotten the hang of it, could you check this code below and let me know if there are any glaring errors?

```
/*------- collapser -------*/
function Collapse(){
    var $this = this;
    $(document).ready(function(e){
        $this.setEvents($this, e);
    });
}
Collapse.prototype.setEvents = function($this, e){    
    $('.collapse>div').hide();
    $('.collapse>h1').click(function(e){
        $this.show($this, e);
    });
}
Collapse.prototype.show = function($this, e){
    var element = e.originalEvent.srcElement.parentNode;
    $(element).children("div").slideToggle();
}
var collapse = new Collapse();
```

One question, is there a better way to get the class instance without passing $this down everytime? I'd love to hook events like this:

```
$(document).ready(setEvents);
```

And in the `setEvents` function, have `this` be an instance of the "collapser." Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You do not need to pass $this to the setEvents or show function, because you can access this (the Collapse object). So these functions can be defined setEvents = function(e) {}, ect.

Comment: that's what i thought. but `this` in `setEvents` returns the `document` object since it's the one "calling" `setEvents` in `$(document).ready(setEvents)`

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8La9D/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you take a look at my fiddle? (http://jsfiddle.net/u4Ap9/). I'm trying to in `line:14` set the handler cleanly (instead of passing a function on the fly that then calls the handler function). Can I get the class instance in the handler function if I do it this way?  Does a `jQuery.Event` object contain the caller instance?

Comment: If you pass the function in that way the $this is the caller, which is <h1> element in this case :). It's the same as line 6, we must encapsulate `setEvents` in a function. So be careful when using this, as it's changed on context.

Comment: You can use jQuery.proxy for this.

Comment: you might get a better response to this question on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Javascript is not best choice for proper OOP. Making your own OOP framework in JS is a complex task and if it isn't your goal try avoiding it and use some framework that gives you OOP features you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone.

It turned out to be OOP enough for what I wanted (singleton web-apps / widgets).

I've since moved on to `AngularJS`.